# cannot install collection in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I am not able to install collection in laravel 5.8 when I use the command:

```
 composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.8.0"
```

I am getting the following error in my terminal:

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>     Could not parse version constraint :5.8.0: Invalid version string ":5.8.0"

```
require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-
with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--o
ptimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try install using singlequotes:
`composer require 'laravelcollective/html:^5.8.0'`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
composer require "vendor-name/package-name:2.1.0"
composer require "laravelcollective/html:5.8.0"
```

- [the-most-useful-php-composer-commands-f6554c157447](https://medium.com/hello-laravel/the-most-useful-php-composer-commands-f6554c157447)

Answer (score 1):

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

use this directly its working 100% it gets automatically version of laravel.

Comment: @Trenton_M It's not, though. None of the other questions suggest dropping the version string entirely, but it tends to work well.